# Bundle size increased after upgrading to Angular 6 (from 5)

Tags: angular, angular-cli, rxjs6, angular-cli-v6

I have a large (hundreds of components) angular (5.2.4) app.  I upgraded the following, and am able to build clean, but the resulting bundle sizes are larger than with v5:

- Node.js and Angular CLI updated
- Http converted to use HttpClient
- rxjs conversion from 5 to 6 (pipe operators)
- converted .angular-cli.json to new angular.json
- removed/replaced any deprecated usage (minimal)

We build using an npm script like the following due to a known issue with the JS heap causing grief:

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --target=production --aot=true --progress=false --env=STAGING
```

I revised this script to the following based on commands changing in the angular cli:

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot --progress=false --c=USER
```

Prior to upgrading, our main bundle size was ~9MB.  After upgrading, it's ~21MB.  Any thoughts or suggestions to diagnose this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#inspect-the-bundles. Even 9MB is an awful lot. Why don't you use lazy loading?

Comment: My build size was at around 7MB+ on 1.7.4 (I know it was big already), but now it's 40.5MB! This is with --prod. Without prod it became almost twice as much which is insane. I'm really happy to hear if you find some reasons for this...

Answer (score 0):

With the very little information that you provided. I assume that since Rxjs changes the way we import stuff, you may have stacked imports types 5 & 6

Comment: I haven't stacked imports and I have the same issue.